# bash execute multi command built with strings from pipe

Tags: bash

We have ip rules

```
# ip rule ls
0:      from all lookup local
100:    from 10.10.0.114 lookup RT0
100:    from 10.8.0.118 lookup RT0
100:    from 10.10.0.97 lookup RT1
220:    from all lookup 220
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

and we want to execute the following command according to the `ip rule ls` result:

```
ip rule del from 10.10.0.114 lookup RT0
ip rule del from 10.8.0.118 lookup RT0
ip rule del from 10.10.0.97 lookup RT1
```

I have tried following command but got no luck

```
for i in $(ip rule ls | grep lookup | grep -v all | awk '{print $2,$3,$4,$5}'); do ip rule del $i;done
```

But it seems that was wrong

How can we do that?

Comment: What do you mean with "it seems that was wrong"? What kind of error or wrong output did you get?

Comment: Your question was already answered here https://askubuntu.com/questions/344407/how-to-read-complete-line-in-for-loop-with-spaces

Comment: See [Bash Pitfalls #1 (for f in $(ls *.mp3))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) and [Why you don't read lines with "for"](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ip rule ls | awk '/lookup/ && !/all/{print "ip rule del", $2, $3, $4, $5;}' | sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean pure Bash (except for the `ip`) solution:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

ip rule ls  |   while read -r -a f; do
                    (( ${#f[*]} == 5 ))     || continue
                    [[ ${f[1]} == from ]]   || continue
                    [[ ${f[2]} != all ]]    || continue
                    [[ ${f[3]} == lookup ]] || continue
                    ip rule del from "${f[2]}" lookup "${f[4]}"
                done
```

It's hyper-picky about checking that the output from `ip rule ls` has *exactly* the expected format because I've found that it pays to be very careful when writing code that deletes things.

Answer (score -1):

You could try

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS='
'
for i in $(ip rule ls | grep lookup | grep -v all | awk '{print $2,$3,$4,$5}')
do
    echo $i | xargs ip rule del
done
```

Comment: See [Bash Pitfalls #1 (for f in $(ls *.mp3))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) and [Why you don't read lines with "for"](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).